# Listing deals with their products

Tags: rest, pipedrive-api

I need to list all the deals and their products using Pipedrive REST API. Anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can get all Deals with [this call](https://developers.pipedrive.com/docs/api/v1/#!/Deals/get_deals): *GET /deals*

After retrieving the response, you can iterate every Deal and call [another API call](https://developers.pipedrive.com/docs/api/v1/#!/Deals/get_deals_id_products): *GET /deals/{id}/products*

So a (pseudo-)code example could look something like this:

```
DEALS = GET /deals

for DEAL in DEALS
  DEAL_ID = DEAL.ID
  PRODUCTS = GET /deals/DEAL_ID/products
```